# How many Testers role I can assign to a Facebook App before its reveiw?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how many testers I can assign to a Facebook App to have real fiends testers feedback before launch it out. I didn't find any specification.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the maximum number of testers you can have on an app, but according to facebook documentation on test-users [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#rules):

> Each app can create a maximum of 2000 test users.

So I'd say you can have 2000 or more testers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 2000 is related to Tester (not real Facebook user). What I was referring to is real friends that you find into Roles tab (the same tab of Admins, Developers, ecc...)
After having asked a similar question (more contextualized) into Dev Facebook Group I've got an answer that says:"I don't know the exact limit on each of these roles (I'm not sure we publish them). But I'd strongly recommend only testing with a limited set of people/moderators initially by adding them as Testers."